# Continuity of the linear map $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\cdot x_k$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let
$$E:\{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} : \forall k \ x_k \in \mathbb{R}, \exists N\ge 0: \forall n \ge N \ x_n = 0 \} \\ L:(E,\|\cdot \|_\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\ \ \  (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\cdot x_k$$
be a function on the linear space $(E,\|\cdot \|_\infty$).

Show that $L$ is not continuous.

I have already proven that $L$ is linear but have no idea how to show that it is continuous. I've tried the epsilon-delta-definition but this approach does not seem to work out for me.

Comment: Please define $E$.

Comment: You may not need it, but the infinity norm would still work if E was as large as the set of all bounded sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Assume it were continuous. Then, according to the Hahn-Banach theorem, there would be a continuous extension $\tilde{L}:c_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $c_0$ is the space of sequences that converge to $0$. It is well known (see e.g. Alt - Linear functional analysis) that then there exists some $y \in \ell^1$ such that
$$
\tilde{L}(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty x_k y_k
$$
for all $x \in c_0$. But if we choose the unit vectors (that live in $E$ and $\tilde{L} \vert_{E} = L$ by construction), we then have
$$
\tilde{L}(e_i) = y_i = L(e_i) = i.
$$
So $y_i = i$, but then $y \notin \ell^1$, which is a contradiction.

This proves that every operator $T:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
$$
T(x) := \sum_{k = 1}^\infty a_kx_k
$$
is discontinuous if $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \notin \ell^1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $L(e_{n})=n\rightarrow\infty$, where $e_{n}$ is the standard vector with $n$th entry $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$L$ is not continuous at $0$: let $\epsilon > 0$. For any $\delta > 0$, we may choose $N$ such that $N\frac{\delta}{2} > \epsilon$. Note that $(y_n)=(0,0,\ldots,\frac{\delta}{2},0,\ldots)$, where the $\frac{\delta}{2}$ is in the $N$th position, has $||(y_n)||_\infty < \delta$ but also $||L(y_n)||_\infty = N\frac{\delta}{2} > \epsilon$.